# iOS: Photos app taking 800 MB after deleting all photos

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app

I have iOS 10 with Photos library taking 32 GB on iCloud. It was taking 2 GB on my iPhone 6, which was all the space left. I tried to completely disable iCloud and delete all the photos. After one hour, the deletion has stopped, but the Photos library is still taking 800 MB! I tried to connect the phone to iTunes/Image capture, but with no effect. It seems to be empty, but it is not.

[[image: No photos neither videos[1]]
[image: Only this screenshot]
[image: 870 MB used]

Comment: Any photos in the "Recently Deleted" folder? They might still be taking up space.

Comment: Yes, I've deleted them. There were only a few.

Answer (score 2):

Check under Photos' Recently Deleted album. From the Albums view, it appears as a trash can.

Since iOS 8, photos that have been deleted remain on your phone under the Recently Deleted album and are automatically deleted after 30 days, or until you delete them yourself, after which they are permanently gone.

The images in this album still occupy space on your phone. To remove them, go into the album, tap "Select" in the top right corner, and then "Delete All" in the bottom left corner.

Comment: After doing that, do a hard reset (hold Sleep + Home on iPhone 6s or earlier, Sleep + Volume Down on iPhone 7 or later) to ensure that the deleted items are actually deleted. Often iOS does not fully delete data until a hard reset is done.

Comment: I've deleted the recently deleted images. There were only a few of them.